# Porcelain Light fixture under beach house

Tags: lighting, outdoor, porch, porcelain

I have a house at the beach but it is several hundred yards from the ocean. The house is on poles and I would like to install porcelain light fixtures under it to screw Led lights into. Are the porcelain fixtures safe for use outside under the house?[image]

Comment: Think being that close to the ocean, might want sealed light fixtures to protect connections from salt.

Comment: There are tons of outdoor rated fixtures you could use.  The one you pictured is NOT one of them.  Just search for outdoor fixtures, protected would be good too.  Here is a link to just one of them:   https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwic8OyVl_T6AhWHMq0GHdCSBjkYABALGgJwdg&sig=AOD64_1Mqjv_mVtWnkrZVFK5Siygs4LCjg&adurl&ctype=5&ved=2ahUKEwio7OCVl_T6AhX7BzQIHUG_AY8Qvhd6BAgBEHI

Answer (score 2):

That fixture isn't rated for outdoor use. You'd be better off getting outdoor fixtures like the one below  or any of the many available at your home store. You'll also need outdoor junction boxes to attach the fixtures to.

[image]